# WCF closing connection unexpected when the client expects data

Tags: c#, wcf, connection

I have a simple server/client setup using WCF. My problem is that any method expecting a return value yields in an exception due to a unexpectedly closed connection server

[Conifguration file on server side](http://pastebin.com/pWse574y)

[Configuratoin file on client side](http://pastebin.com/WTYJp1nG)

All data classes are in an external project within the `MSO.ErrorSystem.Shared.Datatypes`
The code calling the method:

```
using (var client = Util.GetSearchServiceClient())
{
  ViewBag.Results = client.SearchReports(searchTerm, page, 50);
}
```

`Util.GetSearchServiceClient()`:

```
public static SearchServiceClient GetSearchServiceClient()
{
  SearchServiceClient client = new SearchServiceClient();
    client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
  return client;
}
```

The method called on server side:

```
 public IEnumerable<Shared.Datatypes.Report> SearchReports(string pSearchterm, int pPageNum, int pPageSize)
    {
        using (var session = DatabaseManager.Instance.DocumentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            return session.Query<Report>().Where(r => Regex.IsMatch(r.Title, pSearchterm) || Regex.IsMatch(r.Text, pSearchterm))
                                            .OrderBy(r => r.Open).OrderBy(r => r.LastEdited).Skip(pPageNum * pPageSize).Take(pPageSize);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: [Exception in question](http://pastebin.com/0FVQ0yDH)

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly open the connection.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/10/26/best-practice-always-open-wcf-client-proxy-explicitly-when-it-is-shared.aspx

Try:

```
using (var client = new SearchServiceClient())
{
  client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
  client.Open();
  ViewBag.Results = client.SearchReports(searchTerm, page, 50);
  client.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It doesn't work though but throws out the same exception